# How to display two cols of div so that it do not get wrapped when browser resized? I m using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1115px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.profile-pic {
    margin-top: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 profile-pic"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="image/setu.png" alt="Setu Shubham">
            </div>
            <h1 class="col-sm-6 text-right middle"> Abhi</h1>
            <h3 class="profession text-right">FRONT-END</h3>
        </div>
</header>
```

Hi everyone, I am using bootstrap, I want my image and h1 to be at at same row, image to be at extreme left and heading to be at extreme right when browser gets resized. When I am resizing image comes at top, and my heading goes down, which is not looking good.

[problem i m facing is shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxTkA.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want name and profession in a column on the right, you should put them in some container (not `.container`, just a new parent element) with the class `.col-**-6`.
In following example, I'm switching to `-xs-` for resolutions lesser than 768px. I also removed centering of `.container` because it's already done by BS afaik.

EDIT: [working example in Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MK2QVrJE1C)

Relevant documentation: [Bootstrap 3.x Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```css
.col-xs-6 {
  outline: 1px dashed darkred;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1115px;
    /*margin: 0 auto; already applied by BS afaik*/
}
.profile-pic {
    margin-top: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 profile-pic"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="image/setu.png" alt="Setu Shubham">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <h1 class="text-right middle"> Abhi</h1>
              <h3 class="profession text-right">FRONT-END</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```